# Refering to class variables without creating an instance in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a class which is basically a data structure to hold status codes and an associated dict with each status code. I want to call a method, providing a numeric status code and get a dictionary back.

```
class StatusCode(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.codes  = {  0: { 'flag': "QEX_OK",      'message': "job successful"                                          },
                         1: { 'flag': "QEX_CMDLINE", 'message': "general cmd line syntax or semantic error"               }
             }
    @staticmethod
    def get_code(code):
        return self.codes[code]
```

How would I correctly achieve this?

Much thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@classmethod`:

```
class StatusCode(object):
    codes  = {
            0: { 'flag': "QEX_OK",      'message': "job successful"                           },
            1: { 'flag': "QEX_CMDLINE", 'message': "general cmd line syntax or semantic error"},
            }

    @classmethod
    def get_code(cls, code):
        return cls.codes[code]
```

Comment: What is "cls" in this example?

Comment: @BenH it's the *class* object, analogous to the *instance* object `self` in instance methods.

Comment: It's a reference to `StatusCode` class object, like `self` is reference to a created object instance

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
class StatusCode(object):
    codes  = {0: { 'flag': "QEX_OK",      'message': "job successful"                                          },
              1: { 'flag': "QEX_CMDLINE", 'message': "general cmd line syntax or semantic error"               }
             }

    @staticmethod
    def get_code(code):
        return StatusCode.codes[code]

print StatusCode.get_code(1)
```

Comment: Awesome this is what I needed.... I was messing around with init() and didn't need to. Much thx.